# According to Islam, is it permissible or forbidden for girls to get education from male teachers?

Tags: women, education

In this modern age, today there is an arrangement of coeducation in many universities, schools and colleges and most of teachers are male who teach both boys and girls. And even if there is no coeducation rule then male teachers are also appointed to teach girls.

**So, I want to know that according to Islam, is it permissible for girls/ women to gain knowledge and to get education from male teachers / Scholars or not?**

Comment: A teacher is no different that any other person so if girls are allowed to meet, talk, and interact with male non-relatives, they can do it with teachers. But, if they are not allowed to, they can't do it with teachers either.

Answer (score -1):

well consider the following [Hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/8), in Al-Bukhari:

> *Narrated 'Is-haq*:
>
> Anas bin Malik said, "My grandmother Mulaika invited Allah's Messenger (pbuh) for a meal which she herself had prepared. He ate from it and said, 'Get up! I will lead you in the prayer.' " Anas added, "I took my Hasir, washed it with water as it had become dark because of long use and Allah's Messenger (pbuh) stood on it. The orphan (Damira or Ruh) and I aligned behind him and the old lady (Mulaika) stood behind us. Allah's Messenger (pbuh) led us in the prayer and offered two rak`at and then left."

If the Prophet can lead the women of a household in prayer, it would seems that having male teachers teach girls or women is certainly possible.

Comment: Your logic fails to some extent, an imam doesn't interact in prayer with those he is leading, while a teacher would speak, ask and listen to his students. And have you checked whether the prophet pbuh was a mahram of this lady or whether hijab etc. was already ordered at the time... maybe he in such cases might have a special status. I just want to remind you of verse: [(17:36)](http://legacy.quran.com/17/36) "And do not pursue that of which you have no knowledge. ..." on the whole this hadith hardly can be used as an evidence!

Comment: @medi1saif: it's not logic I'm looking at but analogy or [Qiyas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qiyas) which is part of the methodology of the Hanafi school of jurispudence; I also say it's 'possible' and not of course obligatory, or best; other considerations obviously need to be taken into account; as for never pursuing what we don't have knowledge of then we would never be able to make the first step onto the road of knowledge - would you not agree that is impeccable logic?

Comment: No I disagree the first step is to assure that your assumption has a solid basis as else logic says: ex falso quodlibet. Qiyas is a legal methodology but it shouldn't stand before checking authentic texts first. And we are talking about shari'a matters we have no right to play dices with Allah's rulings. Even Einstein said: "God does not play dice"

Comment: @Medi1Saif: I would agree that checking texts are authentic comes first but that's one of reasons for the Hadith collections - that they are authorised collections about the times and the sayings of the Prophet and I am quoting a Hadith.